# Migrate Site from aegir Drupal hosting platform to Acquia hosting

Tags: migrations, aegir

I have three sites hosted in Aegir hosting environment. No I need to move them to Acquia hosting. Here are some doubts I have:

1. Should I need to move the code as a normal multisite setup to
   Acquia?
2. Since the codebase is extracted from aegir environment, I don't have
   any files on the drupal root like install.php, update.php?

Sorry I haven't worked so much with aegir. So this might sound dump. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I do not use Acquia and don't know their service.

> Should I need to move the code as a normal multisite setup to Acquia?

The documentation seems to say that multisite is supported: https://docs.acquia.com/cloud/multi-site

You would probably need to copy the platform from /var/aegir/platforms. If you look in that directory, each directory is a pretty normal Drupal multisite codebase.

> Since the codebase is extracted from aegir environment, I don't have any files on the drupal root like install.php, update.php?

The platform is just a normal Drupal codebase, it should have these files (even if it doesn't use them).

The hard part will be to move the databases, you will (presumably) need to create them in the Acquia frontend, and change the settings.php file of each site to use the new database info. Aegir creates a drushrc.php but in a non-Aegir environment you can just take the settings and move them into settings.php.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Move the website by packing all of the files in the Drupal installation in a zip archive & using FTP/FXP to transfer. Use the Backup & Migrate module or phpMyAdmin to make copies of the database. Replace any missing files from Drupal core that Aegir removes. You may consider doing a complete upgrade of core & contributed modules customized by Aegir to the latest Drupal version. Then run update.php & the multi-site should be working as normal on Acquia Cloud.